# Доступ клиента в локальную сеть сервера OpenVPN

Tags: windows, сеть, openvpn

Сервер OpenVPN поднят на Windows 10 Pro. Конфиг выглядит следующим образом:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
dev-node "VPN Server"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ssl\\dh.pem"
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ssl\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ssl\\cert.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ssl\\cert.key"
server 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0
max-clients 32
keepalive 10 120
client-to-client
compress
ncp-disable
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\status.log"
log "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 4
mute 20
```

Конфиг клиента:

```
client
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote EXTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_PORT
proto tcp
dev tun
compress
ncp-disable
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
dh dh.pem
float
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 0
```

Клиент подключается к серверу, но не попадает в локальную сеть. Пинг до сервера OpenVPN (172.16.10.1) так же не идет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить доступ клиента к локальной сети сервера?

Comment: По умолчанию используется topology net30, а он устарел и не рекомендуется. Не уверен, имеет ли это отношение к проблеме, но попробуйте прописать topology subnet на сервере и посмотреть что получится

Comment: Проблему не решило

Comment: как минимум, на клиенте не хватает маршрута: `route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` (маска и адрес подсети нужны свои), если, конечно, это вручную не прописываешь... а ещё, скорей всего, на сервере нужно настроить перенаправление пакетов между интерфейсами, но как это сделать на win я не подскажу...